# Regex Error in currency

Tags: regex, vb.net, currency

I have a big problem, I used this codes to generate the number to currency,

```
Dim reg = New Regex("\d+")
Dim str As String = dZ.Rows(y).Item(14).ToString().Replace(",", ""). _
                               Replace(".00", "").Replace("$", "").Trim
Dim match = reg.Match(str)
If match.Success Then
    str = reg.Replace(str, Decimal.Parse(match.Value).ToString("C"))
End If
```

yes it works, but what if my amount is:

```
1,900.50 POC
```

Comment: So the problem is with the extra characters `POC`? What string formats are you expecting besides that?

Comment: all i just to do is to convert all the amount into currency

Answer (score 1):

kelvzy your solution is not very flexible. I will suggest my solution:

```
string cellValue = dZ.Rows[y][14];
string cleanedCellValue = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s[^\d.,]+", ""); 
//this will replace everything after the last digit

string decimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(cleanedCellValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string str = decimalValue.ToString("C");
```

This solution will work, when each cell uses comma as thousand separator, dot as decimal separator and any symbols as currency symbol.

In other case give me please more examples

Comment: is this will convert into currency ?
sample 'POC 19,000.50'

Comment: @kelvzy
Delete \s from the second line. It will work
`string cleanedCellValue = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d.,]+", "");`